# How to return a file downloaded from Datalake Storage from Azure Function Java?

Tags: java, azure

I'm trying to create an Azure Functions HTTP trigger that downloads a file at the specified URI from a DataLake Storage Gen2 and returns it to the client.

By referring to the following URL, I was able to create Functions that download files from Data Lake Storage Gen2 on an instance (VM) of Functions.

However, I don't know how to implement the process of returning the downloaded file to the requesting client terminal.

Please help me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java#download-from-a-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
    / **
     * <pre>
     * HTTP trigger
     * </ pre>
     *
     * @param request: Request
     * @param context: Function execution context
     * @return HttpResponseMessage
     * /
    @FunctionName ("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run (
            @HttpTrigger (
                    name = "req",
                    methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage <Optional <String >> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger (). info ("Begin to HTTP trigger");
        log.info ("Begin to HTTP trigger");
        String downloadFilePath = "D: \\ home \\ site \\ wwwroot \\ downloadFile.txt";
        String datalakeUri = request.getQueryParameters (). Get ("datalakeUri");
        Integer size = Integer.valueOf (request.getQueryParameters (). Get ("size"));

        //String datalakeUri = request.getBody (). OrElse ("dummy");
        context.getLogger (). info ("Get size:" + size);
        context.getLogger (). info ("Get datalakeUri:" + datalakeUri);
        context.getLogger (). info ("Get downloadFilePath:" + downloadFilePath);

        log.info ("Get datalakeUri:" + datalakeUri);
        log.info ("Get downloadFilePath:" + downloadFilePath);

        byte [] result = new byte [size];


        try {
            dataLakeFileSystemClient = createDatalakeClient (accountName, accountKey, fileSystemName);
            // FilePath
            File file = new File (downloadFilePath);
            downloadFile (datalakeUri, file);
            result = getByteArrayFromFile (file);
            file.delete ();
            return request.createResponseBuilder (HttpStatus.OK) .body (result) .build ();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String stacktrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace (e);
            context.getLogger (). log (Level.SEVERE, stacktrace);
            log.fatal (stacktrace);

            return request.createResponseBuilder (HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) .body (stacktrace) .build ();
        }
    }

    public byte [] getByteArrayFromFile (File file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream (file);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray (inputStream);
    }

    / **
     * <pre>
     * Create an instance of DataLakeFileSystemClient
     * </ pre>
     *
     * @param accountName: Storage account name
     * @param accountKey: key
     * @param fileSystemName: Container name
     * @return DataLakeFileSystemClient
     * /
    public DataLakeFileSystemClient createDatalakeClient (String accountName, String accountKey, String fileSystemName) {

        // Create a service client
        StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential =
                new StorageSharedKeyCredential (accountName, accountKey);
        DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder ();
        builder.credential (sharedKeyCredential);
        builder.endpoint ("https: //" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net");

        // DataLake service client
        DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = builder.buildClient ();

        // Preparing to create a connection client
        DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient (fileSystemName);

        return dataLakeFileSystemClient;
    }

    / **
     * <pre>
     * Copy the DataLakeStorage file to BlobStorage.
     * </ pre>
     *
     * @param srcDataLakeUri URI of copy source DataLakeStorage file
     * @param file file
     *
     * @throws Exception File copy failed
     *
     * /

    public void downloadFile (String srcDataLakeUri, File file) throws Exception {

        // Get the folder path and file name from the DataLakeStorage URI
        String dlDirectoryName = StorageUtils.getFolderPathFromFileUri (srcDataLakeUri);
        String dlFileName = StorageUtils.getFileName (srcDataLakeUri);

        // From srcDataLake creation
        DataLakeDirectoryClient dataLakeDirectoryClient = this.dataLakeFileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient (dlDirectoryName);
        DataLakeFileClient dataLakeFileClient = dataLakeDirectoryClient.getFileClient (dlFileName);

        try (OutputStream targetStream = new FileOutputStream (file)) {

            dataLakeFileClient.read (targetStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

https://github.com/Azure-Samples

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your file to a byte array and add it to the response body
and add few headers:

```java
byte[] bytes = readFileToBytes(file); //write file to a byte array
HttpResponseMessage response =
    request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body((Object) bytes)
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sampleFile+ ".pdf")
        .build();
```